# Laravel - Alternative for Session in Laravel Socialite Login in Rest API

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-socialite

I am new to Laravel Socialite Login. In my Laravel-8 Application, I have used:

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

for Azure Socialite Login, which works for the multi-company Login. I store the company id in Session.

```
public function getCompanies() {
    $current_domain = request()->getHost(); // your company app name
    $domain = explode('.', $current_domain);
    return OrgCompany::where('subdomain', $domain[0])->firstOrFail();
}

public function redirectToProvider(Request $request, OrgSocialiteSetting $azureCredential)
{
    $companies = $this->getCompanies();
    if($companies){
        $company_credentials = OrgSocialiteSetting::where('id', $companies->id)->first();
        //when switching between different API Credentials
        config(['services.azure.client_id' => $company_credentials->client_id]);
        config(['services.azure.client_secret' => $company_credentials->client_secret]);
        config(['services.azure.redirect' => $company_credentials->client_redirect]);

        session(['id' => $request['company']]);
        return Socialite::with('azure')->redirect();
    }
    return back()->with('status', 'Please select a Valid company');
}
```

Now I want to convert the same code to Laravel Rest API whereby I consume it in Angular-10

I am using Laravel-Passport and LaravelSocialite as shown above.

Since I am no more using Session, how do I now deal with

> session(['id' => $request['company']]);

in the code above?

Thanks

Comment: With an API you can authenticate during the request itself by providing a token using a library like jwt-auth or you can pass the credentials aswell as your request.

If you are asking how can you associate a user with a company one idea would be to store a relation to the company with the user, instead of storing the company information in the session alone.

Comment: REST is usually defined as stateless, therefore all information should be passed an understood in isolation on each request.